# Loading UITableViewCells that are not in display

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm having an issue with UITableViewCells not loading unless I scroll down to reveal them, the problem is that each custom cell has a toggle switch in them and If it's on then I add that cell's value to a calculation, however that calculation is incomplete since its missing some of the cells that did not load (and they load once I scroll down).
Hopefully that makes sense. This is on a bluetooth connection app, and it's supposed to refresh the table every time it receives new values. Here's the code to load the cells:

```
//TABLE LOADING / RELOADING FUNCTIONS:
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return temperatureReadingArray.count //Should return 1 or 9 depending on array received
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: temperatureReading) as! TemperatureReading

    cell.channelLabel.text = channelNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.readingLabel.text = temperatureReadingArray[indexPath.row]

    if (channelNames.count == 1)
    {
     cell.toggleSwitch.isHidden = true
    }
    if (cell.toggleSwitch.isOn)
    {
        if let value = Double(cell.readingLabel.text!)
        {
            print("valid number: \(value), appending")
            TNUArray.append(value)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Not a valid number reading")
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

As you can see, I check for the toggle switch and so far that code works as I intended, assuming all cells fit inside the visible window, however when I run it on a device with a smaller screen or if I get too many values (more than fit in the screen) then the cells that are not visible do not get counted towards the TNU calculations:

```
func updateIncomingData () {

    print ("Received String:")
    print (receivedDataString)
    print("Clearing TNU Array")
    TNUArray.removeAll()
    temperatureReadingArray = receivedDataString.components(separatedBy: " ")
    self.temperatureReadingsTable.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.calculateTNU() //Need dispatch queue to run this AFTER it finished reloading data
    }
}

func calculateTNU()
{
    var TNU: Double = 0.000

    let minValue = TNUArray.min()
    let maxValue = TNUArray.max()
    print(TNUArray)
    if (minValue != nil && maxValue != nil)
    {
        TNU = maxValue! - minValue!
        calculatedTNU = String(format:"%.3f", TNU)
        TNULabel.text = calculatedTNU
    }
    else
    {
        print("Max or Min had nil values")
        TNULabel.text = "NA"
    }
}
```

I hope I am being clear, I will try to summarize it in a sequence of things that are supposed to happen:
- Receive bluetooth string (it contains multiple values separated by a space)
- Parse those values into an array of values, lets assume I get 9 values
- Add one value per cell, with a toggle switch
- Check if that cell's switch has been toggled and if it has then add that value to an array to calculate the MAX difference between values
- Calculate the max-min value
- display the value.

The problem is calculating the max-min value since the array that it uses to calculate it requires ALL cells to load, and the cells that don't fit the screen don't load unless I scroll.
NOTE: I've also tried using DispatchQueue.main.async and reloadData(), however that doesn't solve the issue, since it doesn't load the cells that are not in display

Comment: Under the MVC paradigm you need to store the toggle data from your cells in your data model rather than rely on being able to read from the cells themselves- when a cell disappears from view it automatically gets dequeued and you lose that info. A simple way to do this would be to maintain and array or dictionary that tells you which index paths contain toggled cells - the only problem with this is if your table view is editable, so you need to be a bit careful. Hope that helps.

Comment: I like this idea, I'm exploring the concepts. Just a quick question, say I toggle a switch on the cell, how do I tell the array/dictionary "hey, it was cell X that toggled, not cell Y", how do I refer to the cell's index from within the cell?

Comment: one thing you could do is subclass UICollectionViewCell, set up a delegate protocol and make your collection view conform to that protocol. Then you could get the cell to inform the delegate when it is toggled, and the collection view can then update the model (if you didn't know there is a method built into the UiCollectionView API that can retrieve the index path for a cell). If you are unclear on any of this perhaps drop me a line on the chat (rather than extend this thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the suggestions. As of now I went with a more basic approach since I'm not too savvy yet:
I made an additional array that holds the index of each cell, this array is global for all other view controllers to access. Basically I added this array's number to the cells when initializing them:
Since I will never receive more than 9 channels I made this:

```
var toggleSwitchStates:[Bool] = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

And this is the code for my cells now:

```
class TemperatureReading: UITableViewCell {

    var cellIndex: Int?
    @IBOutlet weak var channelLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var readingLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchWasToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        print ("Switch toggled for: " + channelLabel.text!)
        changeArrayValue()
    }

    func changeArrayValue()
    {
        toggleSwitchStates[cellIndex!] = toggleSwitch.isOn
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: TOGGLESWITCH_TOGGLED), object: nil) //Let the ViewController know there was a change, re-load TNU data
    }
```

And this is how I initialize them:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //THIS CODE INITIALIZES EACH CELL, WITH ITS CORRESPONDING VALUES
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: temperatureReading) as! TemperatureReading

        cell.channelLabel.text = channelNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.readingLabel.text = temperatureReadingArray[indexPath.row]

        if (channelNames.count == 1)
        {
         cell.toggleSwitch.isHidden = true //IF there's only one channel, no need to calculate TNU
        }
        cell.toggleSwitch.isOn = toggleSwitchStates[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellIndex = chIndex[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

and finally the calculation that runs through both arrays:

```
func calculateTNU()
    {
        TNUArray.removeAll()
        var TNU: Double = 0.000
        for (index, _) in temperatureReadingArray.enumerated() //First we populate the array based on the toggle switches
        {
            if (toggleSwitchStates[index] == true)
            {
                if let value = Double(temperatureReadingArray[index])
                {
                    TNUArray.append(value)
                    print("Appending value to array: \(value)")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("not a valid number")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("toggle switch is off")
            }
        } //Now we get max - min values
        let minValue = TNUArray.min()
        let maxValue = TNUArray.max()
        print("TNU Array is:\(TNUArray)")
        if (minValue != nil && maxValue != nil)
        {
            TNU = maxValue! - minValue!
            calculatedTNU = String(format:"%.3f", TNU) //3 decimal places
            TNULabel.text = calculatedTNU
        }
        else
        {
            print("Max or Min had nil values")
            TNULabel.text = "NA"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, the problem here is that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is only called for visible cells, which is why the cells that are offscreen are not taken into account for your calculations.

What I would suggest you is to create a class where you would store all the bluetooth-related objects, and do the calculations only when you got notified by the completion handler of your method.

To do that, you can create a singleton to access your Networking class from anywhere in your project, and assuring that you always only have one instance of it running :

```
class Networking {

   static let shared = Networking()
}
```

Now create an array to hold you data, and put your updateIncomingData() function in there, and add a completion handler to it, like so :

```
var temperatureReadingArray = [Int]()

func updateIncomingData(_ completion: @escaping () -> ()) {  
   // ..Do your networking/bluetooth operations here.       
   self?.temperatureReadingArray.append(newTemperature)       
   completion()
}
```

This allows you to be notified whenever some new data (newTemperature) is coming, so that you can know when you need to reload your data (no matter the cells are visible or not)

Now go back to your Table View Controller and in your ViewDidLoad Method (or wherever you want, be it a button, etc..), implement the following to be notified by the completion handler, and reload asynchronously your table view :

```
Networking.shared.loadMoreData { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
    self?.doSomeCalculations()
}
```

Also dont forget to update your Data Source so that it reflects the number of temperature objects inside your array :

```
// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {   
   return Networking.shared.temperatureReadingArray.count
}
```

And finally here is link to a project I made to show you how it works :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lta464kl3ysilct/DisplayMinMax.zip?dl=0

Just let me know if you have any questions !

**Update:**

Here is how you could do it using a switch and closures to get the switch state of a cell :

First you will need a custom table view cell. Inside that custom class create two closures, one for the switch on, and one for the switch off :

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var shouldToggleOn: ((CustomTableCell) -> Void)?
    var shouldToggleOff: ((CustomTableCell) -> Void)?

    // MARK: User Interaction

    @IBAction func handleSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if sender.isOn {

            shouldToggleOn?(self)

        } else {

            shouldToggleOff?(self)
        }

    }
}
```

Now let's say you have a `Temperature` object that looks like this :

```
class Temperature : NSObject {

    // MARK: Properties

    var value: Int
    var boolean: Bool

    // MARK: Initializers

    init(value: Int, boolean: Bool) {
        self.value = value
        self.boolean = boolean
    }
}
```

In your Networking class you create an array to hold all your Temperatures :

```
var dataArray = [Temperature]()
```

Whenever your loadMoreData get called,  you can add the new Temperature to your array like so :

```
dataArray.append(Temperature(value: randomNumber, boolean: false))
```

*Note : It's really up to you to choose whether you want the boolean value to default to true or false.*

Now in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, it's time to use the two closures you created earlier, and update your data model respectively if the user toggled the switch ON or OFF.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            // ...

            cell.shouldToggleOn = { (selectedCell) -> Void in
                print("turned ON")
                Networking.shared.dataArray[indexPath.row].boolean = true
            }

            cell.shouldToggleOff = { (selectedCell) -> Void in
                print("turned OFF...")
                Networking.shared.dataArray[indexPath.row].boolean = false
            }

            // ...
}
```

Now whenever you receive a new Temperature, the completion handler of your `loadMoreData` method (which I recommend you not to put inside your cellForRow method, but rather in your viewDidLoad method) will be called.

At that time, you can reload your table view and start the calculations:

```
Networking.shared.loadMoreData { [weak self] in
   self?.tableView.reloadData()
   self?.doSomeCalculations()
}
```

And for your `doSomeCalculations` method, just filter and map to choose whether or not you need to do the calculations (aka whether the boolean is ON or OFF) :

```
 func doSomeCalculations() {

      // consider only toggled on switches

      let onlyToggledOnArray = Networking.shared.dataArray.filter { $0.boolean == true }

      // get the min and max values

      let maxValue = onlyToggledOnArray.map{$0.value}.max()
      let minValue = onlyToggledOnArray.map{$0.value}.min()

      guard maxValue != nil, minValue != nil else {
         return
      }

      // ...
}
```

And everything should just work fine :)

Comment: Thank you for that, I already have it set up as you suggested. I do have a BLE class and swift file separate from the rest. The problem is not that. The problem is that each cell has a toggle switch, and I only perform calculations on the cells that have the toggle switch on. This is where the problem lies since the toggled "ON" cells that are not visible are not taken into account. I can't just process all the data, that defeats the purpose of the toggle switches

Comment: Oh okay thank you for the clarification ! In that case I would recommend you to add a boolean property to your object model so that you can refer to it and check whether it's on or not so you can choose to do the calculations or not.  And to know which cell got toggled I would use a closure in the custom cell class

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a data Model Class and initialize that class with all the values which are to be populated in the UITableView.

Suppose if all the cells have toggle switches then initialize your model class with the BOOL values (different properties for different cells) and set them a default value (yes/no)

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
if(modelClass.toggleValue)
  cell.toggleSwitch.setOn(true)
else
  cell.toggleSwitch.setOn(false)
```

And whenever you toggle a switch, update the model class for respected value. And you are done. now make your calculation on the values stored in the model class. Not from the cell directly.

Hope this will help you..!